# GWT IE troubles with width of FlowPanel

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt

I have this code :

```
 private FlowPanel main = new FlowPanel();
 private FlowPanel mainContentPanel = new FlowPanel();
 private HorizontalPanel horizontalFixedPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
 private HorizontalPanel horizontalFlexPanel = new HorizontalPanel();

 mainContentPanel.addStyleName("mainPanel");

 FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
 panel.addStyleName("fixed");
 horizontalFixedPanel.add(panel);

 mainContentPanel.add(horizontalFixedPanel);
 mainContentPanel.add(horizontalFlexPanel);

 main.add(mainContentPanel);

 RootPanel.get().add(main);
```

style.css :

```
*.fixed {
    border: 5px solid red;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.mainPanel {
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

### *

When I open my application in Chrome I get - [image]
in Internet Explorer - [image]

Why width in IE behind the window and scroll is appeared ?? I need to have main panel like in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add some precise width to your `mainPanel`:

```css
.mainPanel {
    width: 100%;
    // or
    width: 500px;
}
```